# app stopped automatically once i click on a button. showing fatal exception

Tags: android, fatal-error, crash

I have written code for simple web browser but when I click on the button the app get stopped showing message "Unfortunately, app has stopped". and it is showing me the fatal exception.

I have posted logcat, java code and also the layout. All the three are there in the same section.

logcat

```
    --------- beginning of crash
01-08 11:31:04.144    2603-2603/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dell.firstapp, PID: 2603
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.dell.firstapp.MyBrowser.onClick(MyBrowser.java:54)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
01-08 11:31:04.175    1242-1935/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.example.dell.firstapp/.MyBrowser
01-08 11:31:04.603    1242-2595/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-08 11:31:04.850    1242-2595/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-08 11:31:04.850    1242-2595/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9f1d71a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-08 11:31:04.975    1242-1260/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-08 11:31:06.604    1242-1260/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{35c22eec u0 com.example.dell.firstapp/.MyBrowser t18 f}
01-08 11:31:06.614    1242-1260/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-08 11:31:14.222    1242-1260/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
public class MyBrowser extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText url;
    WebView ourBrow;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simplebrowser);

        WebView ourBrow=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());
        try {
            ourBrow.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button go=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bGo);
        Button back=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
        Button forward=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bFwd);
        Button refresh=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bRefresh);
        Button clearHistory=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bHistory);
        url=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etURL);
        go.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        forward.setOnClickListener(this);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(this);
        clearHistory.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bGo:
                String theWebsite=url.getText().toString();
                ourBrow.loadUrl(theWebsite);
                //Hiding the keyboard after using an EditText
                InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(url.getWindowToken(),0);
                break;
            case R.id.bBack:
                if(ourBrow.canGoBack())
                    ourBrow.goBack();
                break;
            case R.id.bFwd:
                if(ourBrow.canGoForward())
                    ourBrow.goForward();
                break;
            case R.id.bRefresh:
                ourBrow.reload();
                break;
            case R.id.bHistory:
                ourBrow.clearHistory();
                break;
        }
    }
}



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etURL"
            android:layout_weight="20" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go"
            android:id="@+id/bGo"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bBack"
            android:text="Go back page"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bFwd"
            android:text="Go forward"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bRefresh"
            android:text="Refresh page"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <Button android:text="clear History"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bHistory"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wvBrowser"></WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `ourBrow=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);` instead of `WebView ourBrow=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this nullPointer is you are not properly initialise your webview. 
You create object for global WebView `ourBrow`; and you are using same inside of the `onClick` method  `ourBrow.loadUrl(theWebsite);`. In this case your webview is still null.

In your onCreate method you are using the webview with  the following code.

```
 WebView ourBrow=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
```

So inside of the oncreate method your code not getting the `nullPointer`.

Solution:

Just change this
 `WebView ourBrow=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);`

to

```
  ourBrow=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
```

**Note :** 
 ρяσѕρєя K already added the solution in comments. I am just adding the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please remove local declaration of webview object 'ourBrow' inside onCreate() method of activity. please replace your line 'WebView ourBrow=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);' with 'ourBrow=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);'.

When you declare local webview object than the local object got initialize and global object will still null. And inside of onClick() method global object will access so it is got every time null.
```